# Kill AsyncTask called in perfromFilter for Dynamic AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, autocompletetextview, android-filter

I created a dynamic AutoCompleteTextView in Android. It has the following components.

1. ArrayAdapter with my custom POJO.
2. Adapter implements Filterable.
3. This Filter has a call to an AsyncTask that fetches all the data based on the character or constraints it gets.
4. After getting all the data the AsyncTask parse the data and then return the list to the filter for it to publish.

**Scenario**:
Now when I start typing in the AutoCompleteTextView, after the first character is entered, it starts the async call. Then when I start typing more characters it calls the async again for each character, and the publishes the result through filter.

**Problem**:
The problem is that when the first AsyncTask is called for the first character, the result list is published in the drop down of the AutoCompleteTextView, while I m still typing in the TextView. Then I have to wait for the latest list to be published, which takes a lot of time, as each characters async is executed.

**Code**:
Below is my adapter that I'm using.

```
public class LocationAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LocationBean> implements Filterable {

Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<LocationBean> list, tempList, suggestions;

Filter nameFilter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
        if (constraint != null) {
            try {
                // Downloads location list
                DownloadLocations exec = new DownloadLocations();
                String term = constraint.toString();
                Log.e(Constants.TAG, "CHARACTER: " + term);
                if (exec.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
                    exec.cancel(true);
                } else {
                    list = exec.execute(term).get();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            filterResults.values = list;
            filterResults.count = list.size();
        }
        return filterResults;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

        List<LocationBean> filterList = (ArrayList<LocationBean>) results.values;
        if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
            clear();
            for (LocationBean locations : filterList) {
                add(locations);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
};

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return nameFilter;
}

public LocationAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.location_autocomplete_list_item);
    this.context = context;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    suggestions = new ArrayList<LocationBean>();
}

public LocationAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<LocationBean> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.location_autocomplete_list_item, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    tempList = new ArrayList<LocationBean>(list); // this makes the difference.
    suggestions = new ArrayList<LocationBean>();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_autocomplete_list_item, parent, false);

        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.autcom_name);
        holder.state = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.autcom_state);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (list.get(position).getState().isEmpty()) {
        holder.state.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        holder.state.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    holder.state.setText(list.get(position).getState());

    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView name, state;
}

private class DownloadLocations extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<LocationBean>> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<LocationBean> doInBackground(String... params) {
        if (!isCancelled()) {
            try {
                //Create a new COUNTRY SEARCH url Ex "search.php?term=india"
                URL url = new URL(Api.LOCATION_URL + params[0]);

                HttpsURLConnection conn = Constants.getInitHttpsURLConnectionGET(url);

                String locationResponse = Constants.getStringFromConnection(conn);

                // INIT ArrayList
                ArrayList locationList = new ArrayList<LocationBean>();
                locationList.clear();

                // PARSE RESPONSE
                JSONObject locationResponseJsonObject = new JSONObject(locationResponse);
                Log.e(Constants.TAG, "RESPONSE: " + locationResponseJsonObject);

                JSONArray result = locationResponseJsonObject.getJSONArray(Constants.KEY_LOCATION_RESULTS);

                for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject locationObject = result.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = locationObject.getString(Constants.KEY_LOCATION_ID);
                    String state = locationObject.getString(Constants.KEY_LOCATION_STATE);
                    String name = locationObject.getString(Constants.KEY_LOCATION_NAME);
                    String district = locationObject.getString(Constants.KEY_LOCATION_TEXT);

                    locationList.add(new LocationBean(id, name, district, state));
                }
                return locationList;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("HUS", "EXCEPTION " + e);
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
}
```

**My thoughts**: I think that killing a running AsyncTask before it publishes the result would be a good solution. But I'm not able to do so. Do suggest if you have a better solution or how do I achieve mine.

Please let me know if you didn't understand the problem. Its not a fatal one, but its an annoying bug.

Thank you.

Comment: do you know total no of location?

Comment: @SohailZahid: it varies always, so if i start typing Mumbai, first it will fetch all the places starting with M, then MU, then MUM and so on. Total number of places are more than lacs, hence i used this approach

Answer (score 0):

Here's one I learned the hard way:

`Filter` is actually similar to `AsyncTask`. When you have a `Filter`, you don't need an `AsyncTask`.

- `performFiltering` runs in a non-UI background thread – just like `doInBackground`.
- `publishResults` is run in the UI thread only after completion of `performFiltering` – just like `onPostExecute`.

Rework your code to put your logic from `doInBackground` directly into `performFiltering`.  This will greatly simplify your code as well as make it work the way you want.

Comment: Tried this. It still first shows the list of the first character entered and then the latest updates in the drop down.

Comment: At least with `Filter`, once `performFiltering` is running it will queue up filter requests but not run them until the first request is finished, meanwhile any previously queued requests will be thrown out.  A simple solution is to only call `filter` once the user has entered a certain number of characters.  A more complicated solution is to start a timer when the user types a character, then when the user types another character before expiration reset the timer.  Then you only start the filter request when the user has been idle for certain amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the DownloadLocations object a fresh each time a search is started, try to declares the DownloadLocations AsyncTask as a global variable.

```
public class LocationAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LocationBean> implements Filterable {

Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<LocationBean> list, tempList, suggestions;
DownloadLocations exec = new DownloadLocations();

Filter nameFilter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
        if (constraint != null) {
            try {
                // Downloads location list
                String term = constraint.toString();
                Log.e(Constants.TAG, "CHARACTER: " + term);
                if (exec.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
                    exec.cancel(true);
                } else {
                    exec = new DownloadLocations();
                    list = exec.execute(term).get();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            filterResults.values = list;
            filterResults.count = list.size();
        }
        return filterResults;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

        List<LocationBean> filterList = (ArrayList<LocationBean>) results.values;
        if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
            clear();
            for (LocationBean locations : filterList) {
                add(locations);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
};

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return nameFilter;
}

public LocationAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.location_autocomplete_list_item);
    this.context = context;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    suggestions = new ArrayList<LocationBean>();
}

public LocationAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<LocationBean> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.location_autocomplete_list_item, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    tempList = new ArrayList<LocationBean>(list); // this makes the difference.
    suggestions = new ArrayList<LocationBean>();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_autocomplete_list_item, parent, false);

        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.autcom_name);
        holder.state = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.autcom_state);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (list.get(position).getState().isEmpty()) {
        holder.state.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        holder.state.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    holder.state.setText(list.get(position).getState());

    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView name, state;
}

private class DownloadLocations extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<LocationBean>> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<LocationBean> doInBackground(String... params) {
        if (!isCancelled()) {
            try {
                //Create a new COUNTRY SEARCH url Ex "search.php?term=india"
                URL url = new URL(Api.LOCATION_URL + params[0]);

                HttpsURLConnection conn = Constants.getInitHttpsURLConnectionGET(url);

                String locationResponse = Constants.getStringFromConnection(conn);

                // INIT ArrayList
                ArrayList locationList = new ArrayList<LocationBean>();
                locationList.clear();

                // PARSE RESPONSE
                JSONObject locationResponseJsonObject = new JSONObject(locationResponse);
                Log.e(Constants.TAG, "RESPONSE: " + locationResponseJsonObject);

                JSONArray result = locationResponseJsonObject.getJSONArray(Constants.KEY_LOCATION_RESULTS);

                for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject locationObject = result.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = locationObject.getString(Constants.KEY_LOCATION_ID);
                    String state = locationObject.getString(Constants.KEY_LOCATION_STATE);
                    String name = locationObject.getString(Constants.KEY_LOCATION_NAME);
                    String district = locationObject.getString(Constants.KEY_LOCATION_TEXT);

                    locationList.add(new LocationBean(id, name, district, state));
                }
                return locationList;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("HUS", "EXCEPTION " + e);
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Tried that. It only return the list for the first character then and nothing else.

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() is not used correctly, you are clearing the adapter then calling notifyDataSetChanged() on the first iteration. Do that after adding all items to the list. Check the edited code for reference